# IBM Informix: getting 245, 144 error doing a select while another transaction has done an insert - possible bug?

Tags: sql, indexing, informix, locks

Encountered this problem in production in the form of a deadlock. Figured out that if a transaction was inserting a row on my table, and I wanted to select a totally different row from that table, I would get the following error:

```
  245: Could not position within a file via an index.

  144: ISAM error: key value locked
Error in line 1
Near character position 70
```

My select statement was of the form `select * from table where bar = 3 and foo = "CCCC";`, where "foo" is a foreign key to a table with 18 rows, and "bar" is the first table's primary key. My insert statement was also inserting a row with `foo = "CCCC"`.  Curiously, the select query also returned the desired row before outputting the error.

I tried all this on informix 12.10 with isolation level set to repeatable read. I tried it on production, and in a fresh DB I set up with only the two tables mentioned. The lock mode of both tables is "row".

I investigated by modifying the select statement: `select * from table where bar = 3;` would not fail. Also, `select * from table where bar = 3 and foo = "CCCC" order by ber;` would not fail (ber being a random field from the table, ber is not indexed).

I would expect all the select statements I tried to return the desired row without error, OR all of them to fail. My solution in production was to order by a random field in the table, which fixed the deadlock issue

Does anyone know why this issue could have happened ? I suspect it is linked to the indexes on the table, which were all created automatically when adding the primary and foreign keys to the table. But I do not know enough about indexes to understand what happened. Could this be a bug ?

Schema of the tables:

```
create table options (
        foo     char(4)                 not null,
        fee     int                     not null)
        extent size 16 next size 16
        lock mode row;

alter table options add constraint (
        primary key (foo)
                constraint cons1 );

create table decisions (
        bar     char(3)                 not null,
        foo     char(4)                 not null,
        ber     int                     not null)
        extent size 131072 next size 65536
        lock mode row;

alter table decisions add constraint (
        primary key (bar)
                constraint cons2 );

alter table decisions add constraint (
        foreign key (foo) references options(foo)
                constraint cons3 );
```

Data I inserted into the "options" table:

```
AAAA|0|
BBBB|0|
CCCC|1|
DDDD|4|
EEEE|1|
FFFF|8|
```

Data I inserted into the "decisions" table:

```
QWE|AAAA|0|
WER|AAAA|9|
ERT|CCCC|2|
RTY|AAAA|32|
TYU|CCCC|1234|
YUI|CCCC|42398|
UIO|AAAA|23178|
IOP|CCCC|1233|
OPA|CCCC|11|
PAS|AAAA|890|
ASD|AAAA|90|
SDF|CCCC|2|
DFG|AAAA|4|
FGH|CCCC|7|
```

Edit: I used `set explain on;` for the queries.
`select * from decisions where foo = "CCCC" and bar = "QWE" order by foo;` returned that the index used was on foo="CCCC". However, for `select * from decisions where foo = "CCCC" and bar = "QWE" order by ber;`, it's indexed on bar="QWE".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [SQL tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) about how to write an SQL question.  You've done a lot of the right things, but you missed the schema with the indexes and data.

Comment: Have you looked at the output from SET EXPLAIN for the different statements?  That might provide some insight into what's going on.  In theory, SET ISOLATION TO REPEATABLE READ should mean that a transaction running at that isolation level should not see the database change except when the transaction changes the data.  If you're using SET TRANSACTION instead of SET ISOLATION, [the rules are slightly different](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statement-comparing-set-transaction-set-isolation) — though probably not different enough to matter.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, the checklist that appeared when choosing the sql tag didn't include adding a schema, but it's added now. I also summarized the set explain output, would have to doctor it to post it in full.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'll aim to take a look later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked my question to more experienced people working with me and here is the answer:

When something updates a row in the table (for example inserting a row) in a transaction the index keys for the values inserted get locked. Since I was inserting a row with foo="CCCC", that key value was locked in the foo index. Then, when I did a select statement where foo="CCCC", when that statement used the foo index, it errored, and when it used another index, it worked.

Using [Optimizer Directives](https://www.oninit.com/manual/informix/english/docs/dbdk/is40/sqls/04obj2.html), you can specify an index to use in a query or an index to avoid.

The solution I chose was, first, to define explicit indexes for my table. Then, I used the AVOID_INDEX directive to avoid the "foo" index.

Other solutions would have been to specify the index to use instead (but I was worried the select could use two indexes and still encounter the foo index); to set the lock mode to WAIT X (but since I found the issue through deadlocks this wouldn't have helped); or to use isolation dirty read (but this was unwanted for the purpose of that specific select).

Following the fix, I haven't gotten a deadlock yet.